# Windows shell extension file permissions

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi, shell-extensions

I'm currently developing a custom preview handler for Windows. My setup involves a registered .dll (coded in C++) which calls a .exe (coded in C#) to render the preview. However, I'm encountering an issue where I'm unable to write any files (such as log files) to the filesystem from either the .dll or the .exe.

I've attempted using Windows.Storage instead of System.IO, but encountered a similar error indicating a lack of access rights. The only workaround I've found is running the program as administrator, which allows file writing, but this triggers a popup every time a file is previewed.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Preview handlers always run out of process, and by default in a process with low integrity level by design (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/preview-handlers). You can change that (DisableLowILProcessIsolation =1) which is not recommended or write your own out-of-process server, which is not recommended either but is probably the best in your case if you really need to. So I would change your code to build directly an out-of-process COM server in C# (you don't need the C/C++ thing)

Comment: SHGetKnownFolderPath + FOLDERID_LocalAppDataLow should give you the location intended for low integrity process to write to.

Comment: Which means the .exe process is low access privilege. You can use `OpenProcessToken` to Elevate the privilege.